# C# Delegates & guid.newguid()

Tags: c#

I just started using C# this afternoon, so be a little gentle.

Currently I am working on a type of "template engine" where one of the callbacks needs to generate a globally unique ID. I am using delegates to manage the callbacks.

Currently the code looks like this (though I have also tried an anonymous function & returning NewGuid directly w/o a variable):

```
static string UID(List<string> p)
    {
        string s = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        return s;
    }
```

Which, when called directly, works fine. However if I try to call it via the delegate (added to a StringDictionary via `addCallback("generate UID", new CallbackWrapper(UID))`), the program will generate the same GUID regardless of how many times I duplicate it; even though calling the method directly both before & after the event occurs results in a unique ID as expected. I'v

No doubt it's just something simple I've missed, inevitably stemming from me being relatively inexperienced at C#.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Well, I've now tried Dictionary with the same result.

CallbackWrapper is just the delegate, it's defined like this:

```
delegate string CallbackWrapper(List<string> parameters);
```

The remainder of the work is done in another class, which looks like this:

```
class TemplateParser
{

    private Dictionary<string, CallbackWrapper> callbackMap;

    public TemplateParser(string directivePrefix, string directiveSuffix)
    {
        ...
        callbackMap = new Dictionary<string,CallbackWrapper>();
    }
    public TemplateParser() : this("<!-- {", "} -->") {}

    {
        callbackMap.Add(name, callback);
    }

    public string parse(string filename)
    {
            ...
            string replacement =
                callbackMap[directiveName](new List<string>(parameters.Split(new string[] { ";", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)); 
            ...     
    }
}
```

I've stripped out the majority of the string handling code to save some space.

Comment: I guess it's evaluated once when inserting it into a string and the string then stored in your dictionary.

Comment: But can you link to the StringDictionary.AddCallback method you're talking about? I can't find such a method on MSDN.

Comment: What does `CallbackWrapper` look like?

Comment: And why are you using `StringDictionary` and not the generic `Dictionary`?

Comment: (1) what is the use of p argument to UID?
(2) Normally, UID is call UUID of Guid.

Comment: Parameter P isn't used in the generation of a UID, obviously. The delegate manages a fixed interface where there are other cases in which you need to have a number of arguments parsed to a callback. It's not ideal, I know, but it's for a relatively simple template so it'll work fine. addCallback is my own encapsulation in another class - see below.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your calling code, not in the code itself, nor in the delegate.

Using delegates here *definitely works* if called correctly.

Furthermore, your code can be slightly simplified:

```
static string UID(List<string> p)
{
    return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

(The variable is utterly redundant.)

Comment: @Dan: Well yes but I’m assuming that the method implements some fixed interface.

Comment: That's what I had done intitially, for whatever reason I tried using a local variable in the vain hope it'd actually help. Late ate night, but obviously it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

use delegate.invoke
The difference between direct function call and delegate.invoke is here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/f629c34d-6523-433a-90b3-bb5d445c5587

Comment: This is completely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

StringDictionary will automatically cast your CallbackWrapper to a string, meaning it will only run once and store the output of CallbackWrapper.ToString(). This is probably not what you want.

Try using Dictionary<string, CallbackWrapper> instead.